# Computing a triple integral with cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{2}xz \ dz \ dx \ dy$$

Trying to compute this in cylindrical coordinates, I have that

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{r}^{2}r^2\cos(\theta)z \ dz \ dr \ d\theta$$ which evaluates to $0$. What might I be missing here, this shouldn't evaluate to zero right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is in fact zero. You can guess the value looking at the symmetry of the function over the region of integration.

Comment: What do you mean by "facto zero"?

Comment: in fact zero ...